# How can i display sendbird push notification when appllication is in foregroundmode?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, sendbird

I've implemented sendbird push notification in react-native. It's working fine when application is in background mode. but if application is in foreground mode then it's not display.

In code, I have also set sb.setForegroundState() and sb.setBackgroundState() method with application state.

So, anyone help me for solve out this ?

Comment: Would you mind to add some code to your question? It is very hard to help you without some code as a context.

Comment: please add some code examples and specify platforms (iOS/android), but usually displaying notifications in the foreground has a different flow than in the background (on iOS for example, different AppDelegate methods get called, so you need to implement all of them)

Comment: I am using sendbird on react native platform. As per my knowledge sendbird is not support push notification on foreground mode if user connected to channel, but i don't know exact solution if i want to display notification in that situation.

Comment: Were you able to receive notification when app is in background through sendbird? Because I am not, it is receiving on foreground though.

Answer (score 2):

SendBird sends a push notification only when a user is disconnected. So, if the application is foreground and a user is connected, the app will not receive a push notification.

If you want to show a push notification when your application is in the foreground, you can show it using data in onMessageReceived() or onChannelChanged().

Comment: Thanks @Janna McLaughlin, It's done. I managed local notification on  onChannelChanged() method. It's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can select "Send to devices both offline and online" from sendbird dashboard to receive notifications when the app is in the foreground

Sendbird -> Settings -> Notification -> Push notifications for multi-device users -> select "Send to devices both offline and online"

[image: Check this Screen shot for refrence]